# Spring can not pick a JpaRepository that extends a generic interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oop, design-patterns

## Problem description

I have a couple of controllers that look like this:

```java
@RequestMapping("InkUsage")
@RestController
public class InkUsageController extends BaseController<InkUsageDto> {
    public InkUsageController(BaseService<InkUsageDto> service) {
        super(service);
    }
}

@RequestMapping("MediaCategoryUsage")
@RestController
public class MediaCategoryUsageController extends BaseController<MediaCategoryUsageDto> {
    public MediaCategoryUsageController(BaseService<MediaCategoryUsageDto> service) {
        super(service);
    }
}
```

Both of them extend a `BaseController` class that looks like this:

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@RestController
public class BaseController<T> {
    private BaseService<T> service;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<T>> getAll(){...}
    

    ...
}
```

The `BaseService` looks like this:

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
public class BaseService<T> {
    private BaseRepository<T> repository;
    
    public List<T> getAll() {...}

    ...
}
```

The `BaseRepository` is just an interface that JpaRepositories extend:

```
public interface BaseRepository<T> {
    List<T> getAllAggregated(String dateFormat);
    List<T> getAllNonAggregated(String dateFormat);
    ...
}
```

This is how one of the JpaRepositories look like:

```java
@Repository("InkUsageRepository")
public interface InkUsageRepository extends JpaRepository<InkUsageEntity, Long>,
        BaseRepository<InkUsageDto> {
    @Query("SELECT new api.coloradodashboard.inkusage.InkUsageDto(DATE_FORMAT(i.date, :dateFormat) AS formatted_date, sum(i.cyanLitresUsed), sum(i.magentaLitresUsed), sum(i.yellowLitresUsed), sum(i.blackLitresUsed)) " +
            "FROM InkUsageEntity i " +
            "GROUP BY formatted_date " +
            "ORDER BY formatted_date ASC")
    List<InkUsageDto> getAllAggregated(@Param("dateFormat") String dateFormat);

    ...
}
```

The problem is that when I run the application Spring complains that `BaseService` requires a single bean of type `BaseRepository` but it found 2, which is true. However, both implementations use a different class as a generic type(one uses `BaseRepository<InkUsageDto>`, for example) and it seems Spring can not pick up that.

## Question

How can I tell Spring to use the proper repository?

## What I already tried

- Spring suggests using a `@Primary` qualifier, but that will not solve my problem because I plan on having 5 JpaRepositories extending `BaseRepository`.
- I tried passing the repository into the `BaseController` constructor, then immediately create `new BaseService(repository)` in the `BaseController` constructor but Spring complains it can not find a bean of type `BaseRepository`.
- I checked whether passing a variable into a `@Qualifier` is possible, but they only take constant expressions.
- A solution that will probably work but I avoid is to create BaseRepository class implementation for each repository, but that means having 5 implementations with the same code except the repository field.

## Edit

I found [this article](https://javawithravi.com/spring-generic-type-factory/) but not sure whether it can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found a solution. First, I need to create a `BaseServiceFactory` and pass the repository to the `BaseService` constructor:

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
@Service
public class BaseServiceFactory<T> {
    public BaseService<T> getBaseService(BaseRepository<T> repository) {
        return new BaseService<T>(repository);
    }
}
```

Then each new controller(that inherits `BaseController`) will invoke the factory and pass the repository explicitly(for example, pass `InkUsageRepository` or `MediaCategoryUsageRepository`, etc):

```java
@RequestMapping("InkUsage")
@RestController
public class InkUsageController extends BaseController<InkUsageDto> {
    public InkUsageController(BaseServiceFactory<InkUsageDto> baseServiceFactory,
                              InkUsageRepository repository) {
        super(baseServiceFactory.getBaseService(repository));
    }
}
```

And last, the `BaseService` needs to inject the repository lazily like this:

```java
@Service
public class BaseService<T> {
    private final BaseRepository<T> repository;

    public BaseService(@Lazy @Autowired BaseRepository<T> repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: If you do it this way, you could remove all Spring annotations from `BaseService`, since you control now its lifecycle, not Spring (i.e. you instantiate it yourself and provide the necessary dependencies).

Comment: @dunni After removing the `@Service` annotation the following error is thrown `Parameter 0 of constructor in api.coloradodashboard.controller.BaseController required a bean of type 'api.coloradodashboard.service.BaseService' that could not be found.`

Comment: But why do you still inject the BaseService there, when you provide it through the factory?

Comment: I suppose the `@AllArgsConstructor` does it automatically? If I remove the annotation and add the constructor manually with `(@Autowired(required=false) BaseService<T> service)`, then that works.

Comment: You can also leave auf the Autowired annotation, since you don’t want Spring to autowire it

Comment: You have a point. It was actually the `@RestController` on the `BaseController` that tries to inject. Turns out I do not even need it. I will just leave the `@AllArgsConstructor`. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think your solution is overcomplicated. I assume you have a Parent class (let's call it BaseEntity) for both InkUsageEntity and MediaCategoryUsageEntity. Just simply do this:

```
public interface BaseRepository<T extends BaseEntity> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {
    List<T> getAllAggregated(String dateFormat);
    List<T> getAllNonAggregated(String dateFormat);
    ...
}
```

For these child entites you can have:

```
public interface InkUsageRepository extends BaseRepository<InkUsageEntity> {
    @Query("SELECT new api.coloradodashboard.inkusage.InkUsageDto(DATE_FORMAT(i.date, :dateFormat) AS formatted_date, sum(i.cyanLitresUsed), sum(i.magentaLitresUsed), sum(i.yellowLitresUsed), sum(i.blackLitresUsed)) " +
            "FROM InkUsageEntity i " +
            "GROUP BY formatted_date " +
            "ORDER BY formatted_date ASC")
    List<InkUsageDto> getAllAggregated(@Param("dateFormat") String dateFormat);

}
```

Comment: Yes, there is an abstract `BaseEntity` class that every entity inherits from. Just tried what you suggested but I end up with 6 instances of `BaseRepository` and Spring still cannot pick one. I probably should mention that each entity has its own table.